# CookieManager.check.cookies=false not working

Tags: cookies, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I jmeter.properties I set "CookieManager.check.cookies=false" but cross domain cookies still aren't working.

For example going this [guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) and using their demo site setting a cookie with a domain of "blazedemo.com" works, but if I change the domain to anything else it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter sends only cookies that match the domain of server in the request.

The property you've set impact the way JMeter read cookies  not the way it writes them.

To check, emit a http request towards one host for which you created the cookie, you'll see it works.